# How to pass String values through variable in VARRAY functions in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

How to pass String values through variable in VARRAY functions in PL/SQL.

Coding:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE dynamic_query_build
(
    vr_plan_sku_id     IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  type plan_sku_id_array IS VARRAY(999) OF VARCHAR2(5000);
  plan_sku_id plan_sku_id_array;
  total integer;
  vrx_plan_sku_id VARCHAR2(3000);

BEGIN
  vrx_plan_sku_id:= replace(vr_plan_sku_id,',',chr(39)||','||chr(39));
  vrx_plan_sku_id:=chr(39)||vrx_plan_sku_id||chr(39);
  --plan_sku_id := plan_sku_id_array('Apple','Apple','Orange','Banana');
  dbms_output.put_line(vrx_plan_sku_id);
  plan_sku_id := plan_sku_id_array(vrx_plan_sku_id);

  total := plan_sku_id.count;
  dbms_output.put_line('Array count: 'total);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END dynamic_query_build;
```

**Execution:**

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
vr_plan_sku_id varchar2(200) := 'Apple,Apple,Orange,Banana';
BEGIN
   dynamic_query_build(vr_plan_sku_id);
END;
/
```

**My Output:**

Array count: 1

**Expected Output:**

Array count: 4

**Explanation:** 
When i pass the string values like "plan_sku_id_array('Apple','Apple','Orange','Banana')"  then i am getting count values is 4.. But when i pass the same string through variables then it is considering whole value as single value in the varray.

Comment: Is this really substantially different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17947406/266304)? Couldn't you have added clarification to that instead of asking the same thing again?

Comment: Hi Alex- Its same kind of question but here i am trying to ask people, any functions could be possible to achieve this scenario in any way...

Answer (score 0):

You need to substring your input parameter (based on `,`) and then do something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013874/how-to-populate-varray-multiple-times) (e.g. call `EXTEND();` then `ary(count)= value`). Keep extending and adding as long as you still have some value in your input parameter

Answer (score 0):

Can pass your value string like in given below way. This would convert entire comma separated string in different rows and  you can run a loop and store variables in VARRAY.

```
 SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS
 from t t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(valuestring,':','</e><e>')||  
 '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   );
```

Comment: are you saying fetching the records from table?